# Problem with render layer (normal) in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, normals, render-layers

I have a material made up of two principled BSDFs separated by a mix shader which has a mask. The render works fine but when I see the render layer (normal) it only takes the normal map of the first principled BSD, something that doesn't happen in cycles[image]

Comment: Based on the colors (and distortions), it looks like you have both a tangent space normal map (top) and an object-space normal map (bottom). Maybe one being is "preferred" over the other in Cycles or EEVEE, respectively?

Comment: I don't know, it's the same scene with the same shaders

Comment: It's hard to see what nodes are in the screenshots.  Could you zoom in on them and take another screenshot so that we can see them better?